# Formulas on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I am hopefully moving up with a promotion at work and have noticed a few things I want to change which will help out our planning.

Using Google Sheets, we create rotas for the jobs for the week and what operatives will be where and in what vehicles.

We update this multiple times during a day and are sometimes seeing people's names or vehicles duplicated across the rota, i.e., Joe Bloggs is showing as at two jobs on the same day.

What formula would allow me to create the rota, but then flag up any duplicates to ensure this doesn't happen?

Comment: If the answer solved your question there's a button to accept the answer which might help other people with the same question find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the row in question, go to `Format` > `Conditional Formatting`, set `Apply to range` to all the rows you want to compare, f.ex. `A1:A1000`, set `Format cells if...` to `Custom formula is` and use the `=COUNTIF` function to count if the cell value occurs more than 1 time, for example `=COUNTIF($A:$A, A1) > 1`

[image: Conditional formatting]
[image: Result]